# Google Charts - Table has no columns when it has columns

Tags: google-visualization

I'm attempting to create a Google Charts Line Chart. The Json I'm returning from a C# MVC controller method looks as follows:

[image]

My JS code looks as follows:

```
function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/Misc/GetWeeklySalesData/",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    alert(data);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
    chart.draw(data, { width: 400, height: 240 });
```

I'm getting the message 'Table has no columns' when clearly it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create the data table directly from JSON, it must be in a specific format:

[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Otherwise, you can create a blank data table and load the rows manually:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/Misc/GetWeeklySalesData/",
  dataType: "json",
}).done(function (jsonData) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Week');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Retail');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Wholesale');

  jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
    data.addRow([
      row.Week,
      row.Retail,
      row.Wholesale
    ]);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartDiv'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    width: 400,
    height: 240
  });
}).fail(function (jq, text, err) {
  console.log(text + ' - ' + err);
});
```

Note: highly recommend *not* using --> `async: false`. Use the `done` callback instead...

Comment: Can you explain the recommendation not to use async: false? This was Google's own code using it.